plesk centos2alma failing with unknown reasons
I am performing a centos2alma upgrade on a dev machine and although it says it finished - looking at the log file I notice:
wget https://github.com/plesk/centos2alma/releases/download/v1.4.0/centos2alma-1.4.0.zip
unzip centos2alma-1.4.0.zip
./centos2alma

tail /var/log/plesk/centos2alma.log


2024-09-12 10:01:21,728 - INFO - 

============================================================
2024-09-12 10:01:21,728 - INFO - REPORT OVERVIEW
2024-09-12 10:01:21,728 - INFO - ============================================================
2024-09-12 10:01:21,728 - INFO - Upgrade has been inhibited due to the following problems:
2024-09-12 10:01:21,728 - INFO - 1. Possible problems with remote login using root account
2024-09-12 10:01:21,728 - INFO - HIGH and MEDIUM severity reports:
2024-09-12 10:01:21,728 - INFO - 1. Packages not signed by Red Hat found on the system
2024-09-12 10:01:21,728 - INFO - 2. GRUB2 core will be automatically updated during the upgrade
2024-09-12 10:01:21,728 - INFO - 3. Difference in Python versions and support in RHEL 8
2024-09-12 10:01:21,728 - INFO - 4. Leapp detected loaded kernel drivers which are no longer maintained in RHEL 8.
2024-09-12 10:01:21,729 - INFO - 5. Module pam_pkcs11 will be removed from PAM configuration
2024-09-12 10:01:21,729 - INFO - Reports summary:
2024-09-12 10:01:21,729 - INFO - Errors:                      0
2024-09-12 10:01:21,729 - INFO - Inhibitors:                  1
2024-09-12 10:01:21,729 - INFO - HIGH severity reports:       4
2024-09-12 10:01:21,729 - INFO - MEDIUM severity reports:     1
2024-09-12 10:01:21,729 - INFO - LOW severity reports:        2
2024-09-12 10:01:21,729 - INFO - INFO severity reports:       2
2024-09-12 10:01:21,729 - INFO - Before continuing consult the full report:
2024-09-12 10:01:21,729 - INFO - A report has been generated at /var/log/leapp/leapp-report.json
2024-09-12 10:01:21,729 - INFO - A report has been generated at /var/log/leapp/leapp-report.txt
2024-09-12 10:01:21,729 - INFO - ============================================================
2024-09-12 10:01:21,729 - INFO - END OF REPORT OVERVIEW
2024-09-12 10:01:21,729 - INFO - ============================================================
2024-09-12 10:01:21,729 - INFO - Answerfile has been generated at /var/log/leapp/answerfile
2024-09-12 10:01:21,748 - ERROR - Command ['/usr/bin/leapp', 'preupgrade'] failed with return code 1
2024-09-12 10:01:21,749 - ERROR - Failed: doing the conversion. The reason: Command '['/usr/bin/leapp', 'preupgrade']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
2024-09-12 10:01:22,617 - DEBUG - Going to write json '/usr/local/psa/var/centos2alma/actions.json' with new data

2024-09-12 10:01:22,633 - DEBUG - Sent error report
2024-09-12 10:01:22,643 - DEBUG - Trying to send status of conversion by report-update utility '/var/cache/parallels_installer/report-update'
2024-09-12 10:01:23,206 - ERROR - centos2alma process has failed. Error: Failed: doing the conversion. The reason: Command '['/usr/bin/leapp', 'preupgrade']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
2024-09-12 10:01:23,207 - INFO - Going to free lockfile '/usr/local/psa/var/centos2alma/centos2alma.lock'...

I have tried updating all packages - but it says nothing needs doing
sudo yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: d2lzkl7pfhq30w.cloudfront.net
No packages marked for update

How do I get around this? (and can I run the upgrade more than once?)

It looks like, although I was running this as root (on the server itself - not a putty), I needed to change /etc/ssh/sshd_config to include the line PermitRootLogin yes (and then doing a sudo systemctl restart sshd). Rerunning the cents2alma seems to run for longer after that change
hostnamectl now shows AlmaLinux 8.10 (Cerulean Leopard)
